# How to display edge labels above edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The following code shows that edge labels "cover" edges in `GraphPlot3D`

```
GraphPlot3D[{{1 -> 2, "1\[Rule]2"}, 4 -> 1, {2 -> 4, "2\[Rule]4"}, 
    1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
        EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({If[#3 =!= None, 
            Text[#3, Mean[#1], Background -> Yellow], {}], Line[#]} &)]
```

But if I change `GraphPlot3D` to `GraphPlot`, the edges will go across the labels. How can I keep the labels with the highest z-index? Thank you.

**Snapshot**

`GraphPlot3D`

[image]

`GraphPlot`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "1\[Rule]2"}, 4 -> 1, {2 -> 4, "2\[Rule]4"}, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> 
   ({If[#3 =!= None, 
           {Line[#], Inset[#3, Mean[#1], Automatic, Automatic, #[[1]] - #[[2]], 
           Background -> White]}, Line[#]]} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: @belisarius , I understand what you mean: the latter objects will have higher z-index.

Comment: @ziyuang I don't know if z-index is the right word, but you got the idea :)

Comment: +1 however I wonder if `Inset` obscures the mechanism.  Or perhaps I don't understand.  See answer below.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Inset[] allows "encapsulated" fine control of the superimposed content. You could (and you did, indeed) go without it if you prefer.

Comment: @R.M Good! It's never too late :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have version 8.0 you might want to use the new `Graph` object.

In `g1` I used `Placed`, thanks to Belisarius' suggestion, to move the `EdgeLabel` for 2-> 4 away from the intersection of edges.

```
g1=Graph[{1 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
       DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
       EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 2) -> (1 -> 2), (2 -> 4) -> 
       Placed[(2 -> 4), {.4, {1.25, 3}}]}, 
       EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[20, Background -> Yellow], 
       ImagePadding -> 15]
```

[image: graph]

---

You can avoid the crossing edges altogether with `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing"`:

```
g2=Graph[{1 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
      DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
      EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 2) -> (1 -> 2), (2 -> 4) -> (2 -> 4)},
      GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing",
      EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[20, Background -> Yellow], 
      ImagePadding -> 15]
```

[image: graph2]

---

...or you can make use of the fact that the graph in case is a `CompleteGraph`, which has by default a nice radial layout:

```
g3= CompleteGraph[4, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 15,
   EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 2) -> (1 -> 2), (2 -> 4) -> (2 -> 4)},
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[16, Background -> Yellow]]
```

[image: graph3]

---

Checking...

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[g1, g2]
IsomorphicGraphQ[g1, g3]

(* Out *)
True
True
```

Comment: You can also use EdgeLabels[Placed[] ....] http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeLabels.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented it after some trial and error.

Answer (score 4):

Reordering seems to work without `Inset`:

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "1\[Rule]2"}, 4 -> 1, {2 -> 4, "2\[Rule]4"}, 
  1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Line[#], 
     If[#3 =!= None, Text[#3, Mean[#1], Background -> Yellow], {}]} &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What is the difference between using `Inset` or not?

Comment: @ziyuang I think belisarius should answer that as I'm not sure of his intent.

Answer (score 1):

#### BezierFunction

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "1->2"}, 4 -> 1, {2 -> 4, "2->4"}, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Line[#], 
     If[#3 === None, {}, Text[Framed[Style[#3, 16], Background -> LightRed, 
        FrameStyle -> None], BezierFunction[#][.67], Automatic, Abs[Subtract @@ #]]]} &)]
```

[image]

#### GraphUtilities`LineScaledCoordinate

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "1->2"}, 4 -> 1, {2 -> 4, "2->4"}, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True,
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Line[#], 
  If[#3 === None, {}, Text[Framed[Style[#3, 16], Background -> LightRed, 
   FrameStyle -> None], LineScaledCoordinate[#, .67], Automatic, Abs[Subtract @@ #]]]} &)]
```

[image]